# SQL Error: Cannot cast interval day to second to double (Presto)

Tags: sql, intervals, presto

My table has a column `_range` (type: interval) that I want to use to divide another column `_count` (type: double), but I got this error:

> Cannot apply operator: double / interval day to second

So I tried converting `_range` to double so I could divide double by double like this:

```
select _count / cast(_range as double)
```

but I get this error:

> Cannot cast interval day to second to double

Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`to_milliseconds`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#to_milliseconds) (and divide it by corresponding number if you need seconds, minutes, hours, days):

> `to_milliseconds(interval)` → `bigint`
> Returns the day-to-second interval as milliseconds.

```sql
select typeof(INTERVAL '2' DAY), to_milliseconds(INTERVAL '2' DAY)
```

Output:

| _col0 | _col1 |
| --- | --- |
| interval day to second | 172800000 |